# QT - C++ error: 'QWidget::QWidget(const QWidget&)' is private within this context

Tags: c++, qt

i have a question regarding qt in c++

header file:

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QObject>

class Timer : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Timer(QWidget * parent = 0);
    void setTimer(QString title, QString description, QDate date);
public slots:
    void showWarning() {QString show = tit;
                        QPushButton * thanks = new QPushButton(QObject::tr("Thank you for reminding me!"));
                        show.append("\n");
                        show.append(des);
                        QMessageBox popup;
                        popup.setText(show);
                        popup.setWindowTitle("Calendar : Reminder");
                        popup.setDefaultButton(thanks);
                        popup.exec();
                       }
private:
    QString tit;
    QString des;
};

#endif // TIMER_H
```

cpp file:

```
#include "timer.h"

Timer::Timer(QWidget * parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
}

void Timer::setTimer(QString title, QString description, QDate date)
{
    QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    QDateTime timeoftheaction;
    QTimer *timer=new QTimer;
    tit = title;
    des = description;
    timeoftheaction.setDate(date);
    timeoftheaction.setTime(reminderTime);
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(showWarning()));
    timer->start(now.secsTo(timeoftheaction)*1000);
}
```

When i compile i get the error:

> ........\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include/QtGui/qwidget.h: In
>   copy constructor 'Timer::Timer(const Timer&)':
>   ..\projectOOI/timer.h:9:   instantiated from 'void
>   QList::node_construct(QList::Node*, const T&) [with T =
>   appointment]'
>   ........\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include/QtCore/qlist.h:512:
>   instantiated from 'void QList::append(const T&) [with T =
>   appointment]' ..\projectOOI/appointoverview.h:10:   instantiated from
>   here
>   ........\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include/QtGui/qwidget.h:806:
>   **error: 'QWidget::QWidget(const QWidget&)' is private
>   ..\projectOOI/timer.h:9: error: within this context**

although i have inherited QWidget publicaly... so i do not get where i go wrong

Comment: Looks like `Qwidget` is non-copyable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because QObject (and thus QWidget by inheritance) has a private copy constructor.

Generally speaking you should be pass your object around by pointer/reference instead of by value to avoid using the copy constructor.  Alternatively you should be able to define your own copy constructor.

From the Qt documentation

> QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator.
> This is by design. Actually, they are declared, but in a private
> section with the macro Q_DISABLE_COPY(). In fact, all Qt classes
> derived from QObject (direct or indirect) use this macro to declare
> their copy constructor and assignment operator to be private. The
> reasoning is found in the discussion on Identity vs Value on the Qt
> Object Model page.
>
> The main consequence is that you should use
> pointers to QObject (or to your QObject subclass) where you might
> otherwise be tempted to use your QObject subclass as a value. For
> example, without a copy constructor, you can't use a subclass of
> QObject as the value to be stored in one of the container classes. You
> must store pointers.